# Maven compile error [package org.testng.asserts does not exist]

Tags: maven, testng

When I try to build project via console by [mvn clean install -DskipTests] I get error. I use in my tests testNG SoftAssert and in a test class I just added an import import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert but looks like maven does not see that package. 
Error from console:

> package org.testng.asserts does not exist

My pom.xml looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.atlassian</groupId>
<artifactId>tests</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>confluence</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Is maven identifying other `TestNG` classes? Like when you use `@Test`, does it give similar error?

Answer (score 1):

Such errors occur when corresponding dependency version do not have the classes you are trying to use. In this case the `TestNG version 6.1.1` you are using, does not have package `org.testng.asserts`. Try using below version,
Also, it will not give error for `SoftAsserts` import, if you have asked IDE to include `TestNG library`. This `TestNG` library surely is of higher version than the one you are referring from `pom.xml`. Try to keep same versions both in `pom.xml` & your IDE's `testNG plugin` to avoid such varying behavior.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.8</version>
 </dependency>
```

Above version is surely working. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that removing scope inside testng dependency worked. I tried running with scope added to the same dependency but failed. Strange but it just worked by removing testng scope dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Tried different versions, but it did not help. Removing a scope from dependency indeed solved the issue.