# Code builds fine from eclipse but throwing compile time errors from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins , i have selenium code which i am building using maven. I have mentioned the maven's testng.xml file in pom.xml when i run pom.xml file as maven -> build from Eclipes, the code build fine and project's jar file even generated . I have integrated the same code in to Jenkins job. When i run the job I have observed that Jenkins is not downloading the jars from pom.xml [cause i am not seeing any jar download logs in Jenkin job console] and its throwing error saying package not found

```
ajnakir@WKWIN9326287 MINGW64 /c/D/QURATE/LoggingAndAssertExample (master)
$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------< com.sapient.mercury:PageFactoryFrameWork >-------- 
------
[INFO] Building PageFactoryFrameWork 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------
```

---

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ 
PageFactoryFrameWork ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\D\QURATE\LoggingAndAssertExample\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ 
PageFactoryFrameWork ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered 
resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ 
PageFactoryFrameWork ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, 
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to 
C:\D\QURATE\LoggingAndAssertExample\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/D/QURATE/LoggingAndAssertExample/src/main/java/
com/banking/resources/BasePage.java:[17,26] package org.testng.asserts 
does not exist
[ERROR] 

/C:/D/QURATE/LoggingAndAssertExample/src/main/java/
com/banking/resources/BasePage.java:[23,23] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class SoftAssert
location: class com.banking.resources.BasePage
[ERROR] /C:/D/QURATE/LoggingAndAssertExample/src/main/
java/com/banking/resources/Browser.java:[16,26] package 
org.testng.asserts does not exist
[ERROR] 
 /C:/D/QURATE/LoggingAndAssertExample/src/main/java/
 com/banking/resources/Browser.java:[23,23] cannot find symbol
 symbol:   class SoftAssert
 location: class com.banking.resources.Browser
 [ERROR] 

 /C:/D/QURATE/LoggingAndAssertExample/src/main/java/
 com/banking/resources/Browser.java:[23,51] cannot find symbol
 symbol:   class SoftAssert
 location: class com.banking.resources.Browser
 [INFO] 5 errors
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
 -------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
  -------
 [INFO] Total time:  2.542 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-14T19:15:25+05:30
 [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
 -------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- 
 plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project PageFactoryFrameWork: 
 Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
 [ERROR] 
 /C:/D/QURATE/LoggingAndAssertExample/src/main/java/
 com/banking/resources/BasePage.java:[17,26] package org.testng.asserts 
 does not exist
```

Please help me how should i proceed

I have cross checked and made sure that all necessary plugins and mappings like Git hub repo url is available. I am even able to run another project which have the source from my local

Comment: Please show us the `pom.xml`

Comment: Check the scope of testng dependency. Remove <scope>test</scope>

Comment: Related question: [Maven compile error **package org.testng.asserts does not exist**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34056374/3092298).

Comment: @RahulL i have removed scope for testng dependency from pom.xml and the build is Successfult. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to explicitly add [TestNG dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.14.3) to your [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In general as per [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) best practices you should not have any assertions in the Page Object classes, their goal is to provide an abstraction layer between UI and test logic so you should have only [WebElements](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) definitions and helper functions there, but [Assertions](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html) should be placed in the test code only, not in the Page Objects

Answer (score 0):

FIX: We are not supposed to mention scope tag for dependency in pom.xml, I have removed the test from testng dependency in pom.xml, my maven build successfully completed.